# Confusion about SendMessage function (winuser.h)

Tags: c++

I used the code below for a fullscreen console window. Can someone explain to me what the last two parameters are used for? I read the documentation, and got information about `wParam` and `lParam`, but I still don't understand why a virtual key is needed, and what changes the value transmitted through the last parameter.

```
void FullScreen()
{
    system("mode con COLS=700"); 
    SendMessage(GetConsoleWindow(), WM_SYSKEYDOWN, VK_RETURN, 0x20000000); 
}
```

Comment: The `SendMessage` function can be used to send a *lot* of messages. What are the exact message you use it for? What is your program doing? Do you have a [mre] of it to show us?

Comment: And please take some time to refresh [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also take the [tour] and read about [ask] good questions and [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: The meaning of the two parameters depends on what type of message you are sending.

Comment: @AndreasWenzel i know about that , but why do i need a vk as parameter and the value after it?

Comment: You claim to have read [the `WM_SYSKEYDOWN` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-syskeydown), and yet you wonder what the `wParam` and `lParam` arguments are for? It is rather clearly laid out in the documentation.

Comment: Please elaborate on what is unclear in the documentation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I suspect the OP only read the SendMessage() documentation and not the WM_SYSKEYDOWN documentation.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I read about wparam and lparam separately but not in this documentation =)) . now I understand, thank you!